# check if a user is loggen in grails titanium

Tags: grails, authentication, titanium-mobile

I am building a mobile app that connects to my grails app that uses spring security core.
Im building the app in titanium studio.
How do i check it the user has an open session on the mobile app.
I log in using the with the following code:

```
   var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
           var url = "http://localhost:8080/FYP/j_spring_security_check";
           var postData = "";
           postData += 'j_username=' + usernameField.value;
           postData += '&j_password=' + passwordField.value;
           postData += '&_spring_security_remember_me=on';
           Ti.API.debug(url);
           xhr.open("POST", url);
           xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
           xhr.onload = function() {

                var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                win.close({animate:true});
                slidingMenu.open({animate:true});
               if( response.error ){
                 alert( response.error );
               } else {
                 //logged in now do something
               }
           };
           xhr.onerror = function(){
             Ti.API.error( "Error Logging in" );   
           };
           xhr.send(postData);
```

But how would i check if the user has already logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a custom method in grails using

```
springsecurityservice.isLoggedIn()
```

and do a `GET` request :)

Answer (score 0):

I simply use an application level variable.  It situations when I need to protect data, I always pass the username and password I stored to the server so it has to authenticate every time.